# Would it be concerning to put 18 inch concrete square at the base of an egress on top of the gravel?

Tags: egress

We have a 3 window egress and we wondered about putting stamped concrete square, for esthetic purposes, on top of the gravel. Would this cause any concern?

Comment: Would it make the egress smaller or cause getting out to be harder?  If neither then it should be okay.  The only concern will be it blocks drainage.

Comment: If you are just placing a paver on gravel, thats fine.  But if you are going to pour concrete then you need to compact the gravel first.

Comment: I disagree that pouring concrete would need compacting the gravel—same difference if you put a paver there.  But I wouldn't pour concrete, at least not filling the well (I assume this is a window well) because it needs to drain.